# VBScript: Change css of an element

Tags: html, css, vbscript

Is it possible to change a css style through vbscript?
The code bellow won't work on **windows scripting host**:

```
Dim oIE

Set oIE = CreateObject("InternetExplorer.Application")

oIE.navigate("www.website.com")

Do While oIE.Busy
    WScript.Sleep 100
Loop

oIE.document.getElementById("div-id-here").style.backgroundcolor="#ff0000"
```

Comment: Just to clarify - you are building this for something that only runs in IE or some embedded IE browser - correct?

Comment: Wow, VBScript still exists.....who knew...

Comment: If the VBScript is like JavaScript... you'll likely need to use the camelCase `backgroundColor` (capital C) to get this to work in IE.

Comment: @scunliffe, I **think** this runs in the *windows scripting host* thingy.... (whispers) I'm not sure what that is...

Comment: @Liam virus writers got to live from something, isn't it? ;)

Comment: try add `While oIE.Document.readyState <> "complete": Wend`

Comment: This is not for desktop user browsing... it is for AUTOMATION purposes. Regarding automation, IE beats FF and Chorme!

Comment: if `oIE.Visible` didn't work you probably shouldn't mark that as the accepted answer (as others will think you solved your issue).  If you want to give a "thumbs up" to the answer, you can vote it up by clicking the up arrow on that answer.

Comment: solved now. thanks everyone

Comment: @Azevedo solved by setting the Visible to True or something else?

Comment: well, here is the solution: oIE.document.getElementsByClassName("hw")(0).style.color="#0ee". The function getElementsByClassName returns a collection. Then I had to set the index: (0) thats why it wasn't working. The same goes for any other getElementsBy****

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It works, but by default the window is hidden so you don't see anything.

To make it appear, add this line:

```
oIE.Visible = True
```

Comment: It's good practice to do `Dim elem: Set elem = oIE.document.getElementById("div-id-here")` and later `If Not elem Is Nothing Then ...`, since `getElementById` is not guaranteed to return anything.

Comment: @Tom true, that's a different side of the problem so feel free to post it as new answer.

Comment: Yeah, not worth the hassle. It was more directed at the OP. Either he makes something of it - or not.